# How to extract tag code itself using R, rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape links to content from this website:

```
https://www.forklift-international.com/en/for-sale/forklift-battery
```

Obviously the link is Java script generated, but after inspecting the page code I can see that the url pattern is present there. Here is important part of the code for the first link:

```
<div class="card cardhighlight0 cpointer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" onclick="window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-S2450-12003t'">
```

In this particular example I need to extract this code, which I can use to assemble the final url:

```
/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-S2450-12003t
```

Problem is that I am not able to read this in. I do the following:

```
response <- GET("https://www.forklift-international.com/en/for-sale/forklift-battery")
page <- read_html(response)
page_links <- page %>% html_elements(".card.cardhighlight0") %>% html_text2()
```

In next steps I would to extract the pattern from the text by regex, but I never got to this point, because the needed pattern is not included in the parsed text. As I understand, it is a part of the tag and it is not being picked up by rvest.
Any suggestions how to deal with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access element attributes through `rvest::html_attr()` :

```r
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://www.forklift-international.com/en/for-sale/forklift-battery")
page %>% 
  html_elements(".card.cardhighlight0") %>% 
  html_attr("onclick")
#>  [1] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-S2450-12003t'"               
#>  [2] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-S24160-12002t'"              
#>  [3] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-F80420A-12001t'"             
#>  [4] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-F48560X-12000t'"             
#>  [5] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-RoyPow-F24160-11999t'"              
#>  [6] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-GRUMA-48-Volt-4-PzS-620-Ah-11998t'" 
#>  [7] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-IBB-24-Volt-3-PzB-225-Ah-11996t'"   
#>  [8] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-Linde-24-Volt-3-PzS-375-Ah-11997t'" 
#>  [9] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-Hoppecke-48V-4-HPzS-500-11993t'"    
#> [10] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-IBH-IBG-Smart-Low-Antimon-11992t'"  
#> [11] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-GRUMA-24-Volt-8-PzS-1000-Ah-11991t'"
#> [12] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-Hoppecke-24V-3-HPzS-375-11990t'"    
#> [13] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-IBV-24-Volt-4-PzS-620-Ah-11987t'"   
#> [14] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-IBV-24-Volt-4-PzS-620-Ah-11988t'"   
#> [15] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-IBV-24-Volt-4-PzS-620-Ah-11989t'"   
#> [16] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-GRUMA-48-Volt-4-PzS-620-Ah-11985t'" 
#> [17] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-%5Bdiv%5D-3-EPzS-465-11853t'"       
#> [18] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-GRUMA-48-Volt-5-PzS-625-Ah-11981t'" 
#> [19] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-AIM-48-Volt-5-PzS-775-Ah-11980t'"   
#> [20] "window.location='/en/e/Battery-used-GRUMA-24-Volt-2-PzS-250-Ah-11979t'"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>